# Pip fails to install custom package: No metadata except PKG-INFO is available

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I'm trying to install a custom package with `pip install auxfuncs` but it throws an error.

It was working in a previous version that had an error in its `__init__.py`. I changed the code from `from auxfuncs import reduce_args` to `from .auxfuncs import reduce_args`. Source: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/oliverm91/auxfuncs).

Then I rebuild it succesfully with `python setup.py bdist_wheel` and uploaded to PyPI with `twine upload dist/*`.

#### Error:

```
PS ...> pip uninstall auxfuncs
WARNING: Skipping auxfuncs as it is not installed.
PS ...> pip install auxfuncs-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl // "here I tried with .whl file, but it's the same if I do pip install auxfuncs"
Processing ...\auxfuncs-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: multimethod in ...\env\lib\site-packages (from auxfuncs==0.1.2) (1.8)ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3021, in _dep_map    
    return self.__dep_map
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2815, in __getattr__ 
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3012, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2815, in __getattr__ 
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 472, in resolve        
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 366, in resolve        
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name)
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 212, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_updated_criteria(candidate)
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 202, in _get_updated_criteria
    for requirement in self._p.get_dependencies(candidate=candidate):
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\provider.py", line 197, in get_dependencies
    return [r for r in candidate.iter_dependencies(with_requires) if r is not None]
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\provider.py", line 197, in <listcomp>
    return [r for r in candidate.iter_dependencies(with_requires) if r is not None]
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 394, in iter_dependencies
    for r in self.dist.requires():
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2736, in requires    
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3023, in _dep_map    
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3032, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3014, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)

  File "...\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1895, in get_metadata    raise KeyError("No metadata except PKG-INFO is available")
KeyError: 'No metadata except PKG-INFO is available'
```

#### Setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
```

#### Setup.cfg file:

```
[metadata]
name = auxfuncs
author = Oliver Mohr B.
author_email = oliver.mohr.b@gmail.com
version = 0.1.2
description = Personal library for handling functions
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/oliverm91/auxfuncs
license_files = LICENSE
keywords = function handling
classifiers = 
    Development Status :: 3 - Alpha
    License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)
    Programming Language :: Python
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11
    Intended Audience :: Developers
    Natural Language :: English

[options]
package_dir=
    = src
packages=find:
python_requires = >=3.6
install_requires = 
    multimethod

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the environment is broken.
Try recreating the environment.